# Electric motors high volts low amps vs low volts high amps

Tags: dc-motor

I have a little electric motor that im trying to use to spin a turn dial. I tryed useing a 5volt 1.55 amp power supply but it just dont have enought power to spin it. I can hook it up to my portable battery charger which is 5volts 2100 milliamps and it will start to spin it better. But im trying to find out how to give it power to spin it but not turn speed. What would be better High volts and low amps or low volts High amps?

I asked the question wrong the info i was looking for is which volts and amps will give the motor the most torque without realy changing the rpms.

The motor is hooked up to a pully That is made to spin a Rod that sticking out of it the motor doesnt have enought torque to spin the pully.i need enought torque to spin the pully but not have the pully spin to fast

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the motor?  What does "spin it but not turn speed" mean?  Torque will be proportional to current, and speed will be proportional to voltage.  Without more information about the motor and the load and the design requirements it's hard to say anything more.

Comment: maybe it is not a 5 V motor

Comment: I do not have any data on the motor. I'm trying to figure out what volts and amps will give the current i need.

Comment: "*I asked the question wrong the info i was looking for is which volts and amps will give the motor the most torque without realy changing the rpms.*" It seems that you are confused about the relationship between torque and RPM. If you explain (in the question) what you are really trying to do you might get better help.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a little electric motor that im trying to use to spin a turn dial.

You need to provide the specification of the motor and, ideally, a link to the datasheet for it. If you have none of those then show a photo with a ruler for scale and explain where the motor was found.

> What would be better high volts and low amps or low volts high amps?

You need to decide whether you want to run the motor at constant speed or at constant torque.

- For constant speed you need to supply a constant voltage from a supply that can supply the maximum current required at that speed.
- For constant torque you need to supply a constant current from a supply that can supply the maximum voltage required at maximum speed.

Comment: Constant torque is what i need. Thats what im trying to find out. I dont know which volts and amps will give me the current i need. i dont have any data on the motor. Wont be able to send a picture for a nother 3hrs

Comment: Put whatever information you have into your question, not sprinkled through the comments.